# Check is not between two dates sql

Tags: oracle, ddl

I am trying to verify that a database cannot store information that is within the range of a date.

```
CREATE TABLE works(
    nro_employee varchar2(10),
    job_name varchar2(100),
    date_incorporation date NOT NULL,
    low_date date,
    CONSTRAINT PK_work PRIMARY KEY (nro_employee, job_name),
    CONSTRAINT FK_work1 FOREIGN KEY (nro_employee) REFERENCES employee(nro_employee),
    CONSTRAINT FK_work2 FOREIGN KEY (job_name) REFERENCES installation(job_name)
);
```

For this example, if I have the introduced instance of

```
1, executive, 01-mar-2010, 01-mar-2019
```

I cannot have another instance within that range, that is "you can only be working in one position at a time" (for the nro_employee = 1), that the high and low date is less than Mar 1, 2010 or greater than Mar 1, 2019.

The only way that has occurred to me is the check, but for this I need to access the stored data in the table to be able to check values ​​and I have not found an alternative

Comment: there's also DB trigger alternative but check constraint is better to use. When trigger alternative is used to control the rules, you can have a messy structure like spaghetti code.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan So is it better with check? I can't find a way to apply it to fields already entered in the database

Comment: No, it is not better with check. Even a trigger might be an issue because table will be mutating. You might need to do it via buffering table. But these things often controlled by application. For such operation, you can also create a stored procedure. Or your application can use anonymous block. And if somebody manually screws the data - too bad. However, they can screw the table constraints as well..

Comment: @T.S. I am starting with the creation of databases, so it has to be something very simple to do and that is why I am very lost on how to raise it. From what you have told me I have not understood much.

Comment: What you are asking is not going to be "very simple". It requires design

Comment: @T.S. Is there any question or page that can guide me with a simple solution of what I raise?

Comment: So as far as i understood your problem, you need to restrict the insertion or updation for which dates are falling in between existing dates of the employee? Also is it new table or is there data in the table also that you need to modify?

Comment: @Tejash This table represents the jobs. A person cannot be working in two different positions, so date_incorporation and low_date for a nro_employee cannot overlap. First I want to do it in the insertion, although it should also give error when it is updated

Comment: Look, you have employee and job as PK. So, if you insert it second time (same emp different job), you don't want dates to intersect with previous record. How are you going to do it? If you do it via trigger, you probably going to get mutating table error. I am not sure - you can try: create a custom function where you query same table and then use this function in check constraint on your date columns. But it seem these simple solutions are dead end. Most likely, you need to separate your dates into separate table - employment dates: `emp, job, start, end`. Then in your `works` use this `id`.

Comment: @T.S. That primary key is set that an employee only goes through one position, but what I need with the dates is that I am not working in two different jobs at the same time (start / end date of another job overlap)

Comment: Then, you can use trigger on the `works` and query `dates` table, and it will not mutate. But the consequence, you will need to insert into 2 tables. But this can be mitigated by creating a view and `instead of trigger`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve it using `trigger` as following:

I am assuming that `date_incorporation` is start date and `low_date` is end date. Hence, using `start_date` and `end_date` as column names.

> ```
> Create or replace trigger works_trg_01
> Before insert or update on works
> For each row
> Declare
> Cnt number;
> Begin
> Select count(1) into cnt
> from works 
> where :new.nro_employee =  nro_employee
> And case when :new.start_date < start_date and :new.end_date < start_date then 1
> When :new.start_date > end_date then 1
> Else 0 end = 0;
>
> If cnt <> 0 then
> Raise_application_error('-20001', 'employee can not work in overlapping dates');
> End if;
>
> End;
> /
> ```
>
> [db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b76c6c8f39e04a42fe9676de4685e0b5)

Please change the logic according to the requirement in above trigger. This is just to show you that how it can be done.

Cheers!!

Comment: Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors. ERROR at line 1:
ORA-04098: trigger 'USER.works' is invalid and failed
re-validation

Comment: It was a transcription error of mine. With show error I could see the line and it was that I had left a space between : and new.nro_employee. Fixed !! thank you very much!!!

Comment: I just did similar test and it works. I thought it will get a mutating table error. good